# Остаток от деления на простое число

Tags: алгоритм

Как быстро найти остаток от деления на простое число? Есть ли какая-либо теорема по этому поводу? Допустим у нас есть формула

```
(x1 * x2 + p1 * y1 * y2) % p2
```

где `р1 и р2` - простые числа. При небольших p2 вычисление производится допустимо быстро, но при увеличении p2 решение не проходит по времени.

Comment: @aker: Хм. А что вы подразумеваете под _числом_? У вас, судя по всему, не классический `int`, правильно?

Comment: Нет, классический int. Странное поведение этого выражения, при небольших и больших p1 и p2. Разное время выполнения алгоритма.

Comment: @aker: Хм. Очень странно. Сможете составить бенчмарк?

Answer (score 3):

> Нет, классический int ... при небольших и больших p1 и p2. Разное время выполнения алгоритма.

А как вы это поняли? Вот простенький тест, числа не выходят за пределы 32-битных int, считаем по десять миллионов итераций:

```
use strict;
use integer;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

use constant p1 => 3;
use constant p2 => 5;
use constant p3 => 3996017;
use constant p4 => 3997859;

my ( $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2 ) =
(
    int(rand(1000000))+100000, int(rand(1000000))+100000,
    int(rand(1000000))+100000, int(rand(1000000))+100000
);

cmpthese
(
  10000000,
  {
    'Small primes' =>
    sub
    {
        my $rc = ($x1 * $x2 + p1 * $y1 * $y2) % p2;
    },
    'Big primes' =>
    sub
    {
        my $rc = ($x1 * $x2 + p3 * $y1 * $y2) % p4;
    },
  }
);
```

Разница - да, *какая-то* есть, но на прямо-таки **разницу** не очень похоже :)

```
             Rate      Small primes   Big primes
Small primes 2915452/s           --          -3%
Big primes   3003003/s           3%           --
```

Comment: @user6650 В тесте использованы маленькие значения p1=3 и p2=5, А что он даёт при p1=2147483629 и p2=2147483647?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае с этим ничего не сделать. Можно проверить делимость слагаемых на p2 и выкинуть делящиеся. Дальше человек бы попытался выделить Полную степень и как-то упрощать, но, сдается мне, это будет еще дольше.

Наткнулся в гугле на некий [алгоритм Решетова](http://betaexpert.narod.ru/mersenne.htm), - я не вдавался в подробности, но почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x1 * x2 + p1 * y1 * y2) % p2 =
    (x1 * x2 + ((int)((p1 * y1) %p2) * y2) %p2
```

Т.е. при тройном умножении использовать результат первого умножения по модулю p2 и в формате int.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, по модулю `p2`?

Comment: Для случая, описанного ТС (все числа — `int`) ваш вариант увеличивает количество делений, так что приводит не к ускорению, а к замедлению. Для чисел типа `int` время деления константно и не зависит от того, большое значение операндов или маленькое.

Comment: @Vlad спасибо за замечания, неточность исправил. Единственная видимая причина замедления обработки - выход произведения (тем более - тройного) за рамки формата int, чем и продиктовано предлагаемое решение.

Comment: @user6650 В тесте использованы маленькие значения p1=3 и p2=5, А что он даст, скажем, при p1=2147483629 и p2=2147483647?

Comment: Я понял, куда вы ведёте. Но ваша цель — корректность вычислений, а не их ускорение, правильно? Мне кажется, имеет смысл отметить это в ответе, чтобы ТС понимал недостаток его решения.

Comment: @Vlad некорректно иметь цель, отличную от цели автора вопроса. А посему моя цель - разобраться в ситуации и найти разумный компромисс. Я Вас услышал сразу и потому ушёл от демонстрации свойств модуля в направлении поиска оптимальной по быстродействию схемы.

Comment: Я так и понял, у вашего ответа мой +1.

Answer (score 0):

Если со скобками не наврал, то так:

```
(((x1%p2) * (x2%p2)) % p2 + (((p1%p2) * (y1%p2)) % p2 * (y2%p2)) % p2) % p2
```